# How to decode JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I have an API JSON response like below. I want to decode the JSON to get an array of dictionary `[String:Double]`, like `[{"2020-01-01" : 0.891186}, {"2020-01-02" : 0.891186}]`.

```
{
    "rates": {
        "2020-01-01": {
            "EUR": 0.891186
        },
        "2020-01-02": {
            "EUR": 0.891186
        },
        "2020-01-03": {
            "EUR": 0.895175
        },
        "2020-01-04": {
            "EUR": 0.895175
        }
    }
}
```

I have written decode code like below:

```
do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: appURL)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try decoder.decode(Rates.self, from: data)
            response.rates
        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }
```

And I have tried to define a struct:

```
struct Rates: Codable, Hashable {
    let rates: Point
}

struct Point {

}
```

But I don't have an idea about what I should write in `struct Point` because the date is not a consistent field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions, one with the struct `Point` and the other one with a dictionary instead

First the solution with `Point`

```
struct Point: Codable {
    let date: String
    let rate: Double
}
```

And then create a custom `init(from:)`  where we decode the json into a dictionary first, `[String: [String: Double]]` and then map that dictionary into an array of `Point`

```
struct Rates: Codable {
    let rates: [Point]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let dictionary = try container.decode([String: [String: Double]].self, forKey: .rates)
        rates = dictionary.map { Point(date: $0.key, rate: $0.value.first?.value ?? .zero) }
    }
}
```

---

And here is the second solution using a dictionary

```
struct Rates: Codable {
    let rates: [String: Double]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let dictionary = try container.decode([String: [String: Double]].self, forKey: .rates)
        rates = dictionary.compactMapValues { $0.first?.value }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay! But the two methods all cause a keyNotFound error likes: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "date", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "rates", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "2020-01-03", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"date\", intValue: nil) (\"date\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: I used the json you posted and the same code for decoding as you posted except for creating the `data` variable without any issues so is the json correct because I see no date property in it?

Comment: All is well now! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Rates: Codable {
    let rates: [String: Point]
}


// MARK: - Point
struct Point: Codable {
    let eur: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case eur = "EUR"
    }
}
```

you can do something like this

Comment: Thank you for your replay! The eur is a dynamic name not a consistent field, but still appreciate your work!